# fancybox beforeClose issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a form implemented in a fancybox (version 2.1.5) iframe. People can choose to not to fill up the form and click on "X" to close fancybox form or alternately fill up the form and click on Register.

I have a `beforeClose` callback setup to set cookies and do some work. But I want this to be triggered only if someone clicks on "X" or Esc key. See code below

```
$.fancybox.open({
    type: "iframe",
    href: "/[url].php",
    autoSize: true,
    height: "auto",
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
    autoCenter: true,
    maxWidth: 460,
    maxHeight: 615,
    modal: false,
    iframe: {
        scrolling: "no"
    },
    beforeClose: function () {
        //set cookie code
    },
});
```

But if someone was to Register, it will show a Thank you message for 2 seconds and close the fancybox. This is done by using `window.parent.$.fancybox.close();` See detailed code below

```
$.post('/register.php', post_vars, function(data) {
    window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
});
```

However I do not want the `beforeClose` event to be called in case I close it from the iFrame or even if it gets called, I need to somehow know that it has been done from the iframe & not using the "X" button.

Is there a way to differentiate this?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: @qamar I have added code to the question for better explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think different ways to do this, like binding custom *events* to the fancybox *close button* or catching the *escape* key with `keyup` or `keypress`, etc.

I guess the simplest way is to create **in the parent page**, a custom close function like :

```
var closedFromIframe = false;
function customClose() {
    closedFromIframe = true;
    jQuery.fancybox.close();
}
```

This function will close fancybox (from the parent page itself) when invoked from the *iframed* page **AND** will enable the (previously defined) `closedFromIframe` *flag*, so instead of this :

```
$.post('/register.php', post_vars, function(data) {
    window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
});
```

... you could do

```
$.post('/register.php', post_vars, function(data) {
    window.parent.customClose();
});
```

Then, in your fancybox script you could validate within the `beforeClose` callback, the status of the `closedFromIframe` *flag* and do whatever you need to :

```
$.fancybox.open({
    // your API options
    beforeClose : function () {
        if (closedFromIframe) {
            // closed from iframe custom function
        } else {
            // close button -or- escape key
        }
    },
    afterClose : function () {
        closedFromIframe = false; // reset flag
    }
});
```

**Notice** we are also resetting the `closedFromIframe` *flag* within the `afterClose` callback.

See a **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/detectFancyboxCloseMethod_19jan15.html)** of this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This will be triggered only if someone clicks on "X" or Esc key

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".fancybox").fancybox({

            closeClick: false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox 
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            enableEscapeButton: false,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    closeClick: false // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
                }
            },
            beforeClose: function () {
                return confirm('Are you sure?')
            }
        })
    });
```